# Why the repaint in browser would be defered?

Tags: javascript

I have a `div` with none background color, and then I want to change background color twice. Here is my code:

```
function runForSeconds(second) {
    var start = +new Date();
    while (start + second * 1000 > (+new Date())) {}
}

var el = document.getElementById("foo");

el.style.backgroundColor = "blue";

// do some "long running" task
runForSeconds(10);

el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Between the two times background color change, I run a long time cost javascript

But when I run the page, I can't see the background become blue, after the page can't response for 10 seconds, the background directly into red.

Why this happened? How can I fixed this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript (in general) runs in the same thread as the rendering. So when JavaScript is busy, no rendering will happen.

So in your case, while your code runs, no rendering happens as you block the JavaScript by your `runForSeconds()` function.

A cleaner approach to delay execution of some code, is to use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout), which will *not* block the thread and thus keeps your rendering (and therefor your whole browser) responding to user input.

```
var el = document.getElementById("foo");

el.style.backgroundColor = "blue";

setTimeout( function(){
  el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}, second * 1000 );
```